# vba copy values in different sheets and cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bit of an issue. I have a table with 2 rows and several columns in a tab. One row contains several words and the second row contains the location of where those values should be copied.

For example :

```
  Row 1 Sheet1!$D$1 Sheet5!$F$1 Sheet6$F$1  Sheet3!$D$1
  Row 2 apple           peer            orange          sum
```

So for example, I would like to copy apple to tab : sheet 1 in cell D1.
Is this possible in vba ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show you one simple example on how to achieve what you want. You will have to amend the code to suit your needs.

The below code is an example for `Sheet1!$D$1` and `Apple`. I am assuming that the values are stored in "Sheet2" in Cell `A1` and `A2`. Also I am not doing any error handling. Hope you will take care of that as well.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Sh As String, Cl As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws
        Sh = Split(.Range("A1").Value, "!")(0)
        Cl = Split(.Range("A1").Value, "!")(1)

        Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sh).Range(Cl)

        rng.Value = .Range("A2").Value
    End With
End Sub
```